# Batch clipping rasters using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, raster, clip

Am trying to clip multiple rasters but getting a runtime error, what could be the problem with my code

```
import arcpy, os

arcpy.env.workspace = r"E:\Geos4s\GeoS4S Module Geospatial Support for Arid Ecosystem Management\prec_30s_esri\converted"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

# Clip region
poly = r"E:\Kenya GIS Resources\Kenya New Districts1\Kenya_CountyID.shp"
out_folder =  r"E:\Geos4s\GeoS4S Module Geospatial Support for Arid Ecosystem Management\prec_30s_esri\clipped"
rasters = arcpy.ListRasters()
for raster in rasters:
    out_raster =(out_folder,raster)
    arcpy.Clip_management(raster,'#',out_raster,poly,'#','ClippingGeometry')
    print 'Clipped: %s' %raster
print arcpy.GetMessages()
```

Comment: What is the precise error message, including line number, that you receive when you run the code that you have presented?

Answer (score 4):

You just need to replace:

```
out_raster =(out_folder,raster)
```

With:

```
out_raster = os.path.join(out_folder,raster)
```

Or `out_raster` will be a tuple:
 `('C:\\folder', 'raster.tif')`, instead of a path: `'C:\\folder\\raster.tif'`